# Pulling out multiple indices from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I don't understand the result I get when I pass the upper triangle of a smaller matrix as the index to a larger matrix.

This technique is used in the answer to this question: [Create a Correlation Matrix From a Correlation Vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598574/create-a-correlation-matrix-from-a-correlation-vector-in-r) 
(note: in the linked post, the matrix sizes are the same whereas in my examples they are not.)

In the first example below, why does 10 get printed and why not any other values at indices > [2,2] ? I would have thought only the value at [1,2] would be printed.

```
largeMatrix <- matrix(1:12, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)

largeMatrix
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    5    6
[4,]    7    8
[5,]    9   10
[6,]   11   12

smallMatrix <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)

smallMatrix
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4

upperTriangleSmall <- upper.tri(smallMatrix)

upperTriangleSmall
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE


largeMatrix[upperTriangleSmall]
[1]  5  2 10
```

**My thoughts on what expected output should be:**

```
Either:

2

Or:

2 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

When passing the upper triangle of a matrix as the index to another matrix of the same size, I understand the result.

```
smallMatrix <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)

smallMatrix
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4


newSmallMatrix <- matrix(7:10, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)

newSmallMatrix
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7    8
[2,]    9    10

newSmall[upperTriangleSmall]
[1] 8
```

Comment: Didn't think of that (stupid me), but my question still stands. I'm passing a matrix of booleans as the index, yet I don't understand why the indices that get printed are printed (updated question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see better if you convert the matrix into a vector, matrix elements are indexed by column which you can find out if you access the matrix by a single index, for example, `largeMatrix[1]` gives `1`, `largeMatrix[2]` gives `3` etc:

```
as.vector(largeMatrix)
# [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11  2  4  6  8 10 12

as.vector(upperTriangleSmall)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

So what it does is pick up the third element for each block of four elements, since the length of the two matrix are not the same, it gets recycled and picks up `5, 2, 10`.

Comment: Is this what R does internally to decide which elements to select?

Comment: I am not completely sure about the internal implementation.  but in many manners, matrix behaves just like a one D vector. For example, its elements can be accessed via a single index as illustrated in the answer.